# What is wrong with this simple `unittest.mock` use case?

Tags: python-3.4, python-3.5, pytest, python-unittest

**Edit:** This may be the same issue as described in this Python bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue26752. But that bug has been sitting for a year, so I'm still interested in people's opinions here.

---

I'm not sure if this is a bug in `unittest.mock` or I just misunderstand something.

Here's the code - you can save it as `test.py`

```
from unittest.mock import patch, call

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def my_method(self, value):
        pass

def test_foo():
    with patch('test.Foo', autospec=True) as MockFoo:
        m = Foo()
        m.my_method(123)
        MockFoo.assert_has_calls([call(), call().my_method(123)])
```

I run this test like so:

```
$ py.test test.py
```

And I get this failure:

```
...
E               AssertionError: Calls not found.
E               Expected: [call(), call().my_method(123)]
E               Actual:   [call(), call().my_method(123)]
```

**The Question:** Is this correct behavior? It seems buggy to me.
The list of calls matches up exactly, so what gives?

Interestingly, if I remove the `value` parameter of `my_method` and also the `123` inputs in the test, then everything passes!

What am I missing, here?

Version info:

```
$ py.test --version
This is pytest version 3.0.6, imported from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest.py
$python3.4 --version
Python 3.4.5
```

Also tried this on 3.5 in a virtualenv:

```
$ py.test --version
This is pytest version 3.0.6, imported from /usr/home/jwd/virtualenv/pytest-3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest.py
$ python3.5 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all. There are so many questions, I don't even know where to start… why do you mock `Foo` if you want to test it?

Comment: @hop: This is a boiled-down minimal example of an issue I encountered in a larger set of tests. Please don't expect this code to make sense on its own (:  The issue I'm trying to understand is why `assert_has_calls` has this non-intuitive (in my opinion) behavior when args are passed.

Comment: @hop: but if you must know, in the real code, I am testing a method that *uses* `Foo`. That method is the one that instantiates `Foo` and calls `my_method(123)`. I just inlined it into the test here for brevity.

Comment: But nothing in _this_ code uses Foo, so it is not a valid "boiled-down" example. All you are testing (wrongly, at that) is that functions are called when you call them.

Comment: @hop: Ah, I see what you're saying. Okay, I replaced `MockFoo()` with `Foo()` in the test. The same issue still occurs, and still magically disappears if I remove the `value` argument.  Does it seem like a valid usage now (albeit contrived)?

Comment: You are still only testing a tautology. this goes beyond what stack overflow is meant for, sorry.

Comment: @hop: I don't follow you... Imagine those two lines (instantiating and using `Foo`) were in `some_module.func_xyz()`. I am writing a unit test for `func_xyz()`. I want to make sure `func_xyz()` instantiates a `Foo` and calls `my_method()` on it with the correct parameters. That seems like a perfectly legitimate use case to me.

Comment: You are not testing `some_module.func_xyz()`, you are testing `Foo.my_method()`. If you were doing what you describe, you would have to implement `func_xyz()` and mock `Foo`, but I don't see that in your code. Anyway, this is the last I will comment. Go to codereview.stackexchange.com or #python on freenode, where these kinds of discussions are more appropriate.

Comment: @hop: I think you had it right with "you are testing a tautology" — in a sense I am. I expect this test to pass in the same way I expect `assert True` to pass. Yet it does not. That's the thing I am trying to understand (but thank you for your time).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: deleted erroneous previous answer.

Please can you try:

```
expected_calls = [call(), call().my_method(123)]
assert MockFoo.mock_calls == expected_calls
```

This works for me on Python 3.5.2.

This is taken directly from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls

Comment: I just tried it like that, with the same failure. But then I *also* tried it on 3.5.2 and got the same failure, too.  Are you 100% sure you copied it exactly?  Very odd if your 3.5.2 is behaving different from mine...

Comment: Ah, I think you also replied on the mailing list - I put a more detailed response there. For SO people: http://lists.idyll.org/pipermail/testing-in-python/2017-February/007009.html

Comment: Yes, using the explicit `==` check on the call list works for me, too. That's interesting. I'd expect `X.mock_calls == Y` to have the same behavior as `X.assert_has_calls(Y)` (at least in the case where the lists are the same — I realize `assert_has_calls` does some fancier partial matching in more complex cases).